# Can a Sage use her Infuser package ability with the Chi Gong attack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, class, combat-maneuver, spheres-of-power

The Champion of the Sphere's Sage class has these abilities:

> **Chi Gong (Su)**
>
> At 1st level, the sage learns the chi gong technique, which allows him to wield his ki as a precise instrument, thrusting it into an opponent and disrupting their physiology or reinforcing a wounded ally. A sage’s chi gong is measured in d6’s: the sage begins with 1d6 chi gong, which increases by 1d6 at 3rd level and every 2 levels thereafter. The sage gains a melee touch attack that is treated as a light weapon and can be used whenever the sage could make an attack (such as during an attack action or attack of opportunity) dealing piercing damage to the opponent equal to his chi gong dice; the sage may also apply this bonus damage to his unarmed strikes or natural attacks. In addition, the sage can use this ability to heal a creature instead of damaging them by sealing their wounds together with ki as a move action, but this patchwork healing cannot restore a creature’s hit points above half their normal maximum.

and

> **Infuser**
>
> [...] Whenever the sage could make an attack with an unarmed strike (such as when using the attack action or making an attack of opportunity), or when he would be entitled to make a combat maneuver check on his turn (such as when maintaining a grapple), he may instead force the creature to make a Reflex save (DC 10 + 1/2 the sage’s class level + his Wisdom modifier); creatures who fail their save are automatically subject to a disarm, grapple, or trip attempt (chosen by the sage at the time this ability is used) as though the sage had succeeded on a combat maneuver check against their CMD. [...]

Can she use both in the same attack?

Answer (score 1):

### She can't.

Your answer is inside your own question.

> Infuser
>
> [...] **Whenever the sage could make an attack with an unarmed strike** (such as when using the attack action or making an attack of opportunity), or when he would be entitled to make a combat maneuver check on his turn (such as when maintaining a grapple), **he may *instead* force the creature to make a Reflex save** (DC 10 + 1/2 the sage’s class level + his Wisdom modifier); creatures who fail their save are automatically subject to a disarm, grapple, or trip attempt (chosen by the sage at the time this ability is used) as though the sage had succeeded on a combat maneuver check against their CMD. [...]

As you can see, you forfeit the attack to force the reflex save, if there's no attack and no damage dealing, your Chi Gong isn't applicable (once you're not trying to heal anyone, but it isn't applicable either), so you can't use both together.